# memory error when run pairwise_distances in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

There are 40 million datasets.And when i want to caculated the jaccard ,it reports memory error.How to imporve my code?

```
result=[]
for line in open("./raw_data1"):
#for line in sys.stdin:
        #tagid_result = [0]*max_len
        tagid_result = [0]*34
        line = line.strip()
        fields = line.split("\t")
        if len(fields)<6:
                continue
        tagid = fields[3]
        tagids = tagid.split(":")
        try:
                for i in range(0,len(tagids)):
                        tagid_result[i] = int(tagids[i])
        except:
                continue
        result.append(tagid_result)
X=np.array(result)
distance_matrix = pairwise_distances(X, metric='jaccard')
print (distance_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of RAM. To compute the distances between N vectors you must store N^2 distance values. 40 million ^ 2 is too much data to fit into memory. There are two options:

1) You must split up your matrix, X, into subsets. Create a pairwise distance matrix for each subset. Then stitch those pairwise distance matrices together.

2) You should create a dataset of all vector pairs. Store each vector in its own file. Create a function to read two vector files, compute their distance, and return the distance value. Apply this function over all vector pairs. Concatenate the distance results to create your distance matrix. This function can be run in parallel to compute the distance matrix more efficiently.

I would opt for solution 2.